# Standards of diligence in statutory obligations

Tags: united-states, legal-terms

**Are there established legal terms that characterize the standards of performance of statutory obligations by the government?**  These would certainly vary: For example, some obligations that don't impact constitutional rights can be unfunded, in which case the government has effectively no obligation.  Others are so serious that a failure by a government official to perform to some specified level can result in sanctions.  I imagine in this area there are terms involving the qualifications "reasonable," "practicable," and perhaps "exceptional."

Examples of established legal terms that characterize *other* standards:

- Reasonable doubt
- Narrowly tailored
- Strict scrutiny
- Abuse of discretion

*Further thoughts on what sort of statutory obligations might have a legal standard of diligence in performance:* There are laws that impose duties of performance on the government.  For example, the [sixth-amendment](/questions/tagged/sixth-amendment) imposes a duty on the government to provide criminal defendants with a speedy, public trial; impartial jury of peers; and counsel.  But each of these items is subject to practical limitations: How "speedy" is speedy?  Courts don't have unlimited time and resources, so many courts have decided that continuing a trial for a year is "speedy enough."  What's "public?"  Some courts allow live tele-broadcasts; some restrict access to the proceedings and prohibit recording by spectators.  How far must the government go to ensure an "impartial jury?"  What is sufficient counsel?  Again, resources are limited and so generally a public defender afforded only minutes to prepare for court is considered adequate; but *no* counsel is not adequate.

Comment: There are all sorts of standards. But they aren't uniform. Even the same words do'nt mean the same things in all contexts.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm looking for terms that are used, even if their meanings aren't uniform.